# How to run Authorize.Net SDK for iOS on Xcode 5

Tags: ios, xcode, automatic-ref-counting, payment, authorize.net

So, first things first. I'm looking to implement Authorize.Net iOS SDK on my existing project to receive payments for some physical things I am selling (yes, this is allowed for AppStore apps).
What happens is that the SDK seems to be very old since, first of all, it doesn't support ARC.

Now, this steps: http://developer.authorize.net/integration/fifteenminutes/ios/ are not working for me and trying to find a working project I found this nice implementation https://github.com/sibahota059/AuthorizeNetPaymentTest/tree/master but in order to get it running, you need to turn off ARC, which of course I can't do since my project relies on ARC.

Is there a way to turn off ARC just for SDK only? If so, how can I do it? Is it dangerous?

Answer (score 0):

A new iOS SDK from Authorize.Net is available on GitHub: https://github.com/AuthorizeNet/sdk-mpos-ios.